# Stuck in an infinite loop using jal

Tags: assembly, mips, spim, mars-simulator

```
main:

    jal function1

  #Exit Program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

function1:

    li $s0, 0
    jal function2

    jr $ra 

function2:

    jal external_function
    beq $s0, 5, function2_end

    #Run loop 5 times
    addi $s0, $s0, 1

function2_end:
    jr $ra

external_function:
    #Does random operation
    jr $ra
```

---

So this is just an example of a problem of what I am having with MIPS. I get stuck in an infinite loop because function2_end will keep on jumping to the external_function.

Is there a way to have function2_end jump back to function1, so it can exit the loop?

Comment: Functions need `$ra` to return to the correct place, but calling another function using `jal` will overwrite it with the new value. You need to save it on the stack in non-leaf functions.

Answer (score 1):

`jal` saves the value of `$ra`, overwriting any previous value. What you want to do is save `$ra` to the stack when necessary, and then pop it when you want it back.